# No EntityManager transaction with Spring/EclipseLink

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

In my Spring Data JPA application, I switched from Hibernate to EclipseLink only to find out that now the EntityManager instances are not part of the transactions anymore, and therefore no data gets inserted when calling `persist()`.

If I manually call `entityManager.joinTransaction()` it works, but that's surely not meant to be the solution.

[image]
[image]

I created a sample project that allows reproducing the problem: https://github.com/micheljung/eclipselink-no-transaction
Pay attention to how it does not print an INSERT statement in the console, and how the ID of the saved entity stays `null`:

```
ID of saved entity: null
```

If you include Hibernate and exclude EclipseLink, it works:

```
Hibernate: insert into greeting (id, greeting) values (null, ?)
ID of saved entity: 1
```

I already spent the last 3h reading all related Blogs and SO posts, but none of the results revealed any problem.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
eclipselink.ddl-generation: drop-and-create-tables
```

to your JPA properties (otherwise the GREETING table doesn'† exist),

and add

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
}
```

to your EclipseLinkNoTransactionApplication class.

Comment: Wow, I really must have missed some important documentation here. Thank you so much for saving my day! Any idea why it works with hibernate? I wasn't able to find the creation of an `JpaTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory)` in any of the libraries (only in `BasicBatchConfigurer`)

Comment: As far as I understand, Spring-boot has a HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration class that auto-configure a JpaTransactionManager if it finds HibernateEntityManager in the classpath, but it doesn't have the equivalent class for eclipse-link, so you need to configure the transaction manager by yourself.